# How i obtain 2nd parameter from the datalist in jquery style?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

Here below html code of the field form that shot datalist of customer nr like this:    0001 - Custmer test

```
                <label>Nr. Customer</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nr" placeholder="Choose customer" list="list_nr" id="nr" >

                <datalist id="list_nr">

                                <?php 
                                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT nr, name FROM database.table WHERE status='M'");             
                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {    
                                    //echo "<option value=".$row['name'].">" . $row['nr'] . "-" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                                    echo "<option value=".$row['name'].">"  . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                                    }       
                                ?>                              
                </datalist>

// here below show only 1st

    $('#nr').change(function(){
        var secondOptionValue = $('#nr').val();
        $('#test').val(secondOptionValue);
    });
```

Comment: Your questions is not pretty clear. Explain what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: i select a list for example:      1 - aaa   /  2 - bbb  / 3 - cccc             So i want that when i select 1 in another field show aaa

Comment: I try to use --> var secondOptionValue = $("#nr list_nr:eq(1)").val()         but is not working...